# Xamarin forms: Webview content default size is too small

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I am using a `webview` custom renderer for showing the HTML data on UI. The default size of the webview content is too small.

My Code:

**MyWebView.cs**

```
public  class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Url",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
    defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**MyWebViewRenderer.cs in ios**

```
public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
{
    WKWebView _wkWebView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == "Url")
        {
            Control.LoadHtmlString(Element.Url, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML and XAML.cs**

```
    <local:MyWebView 
    x:Name="web_view"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</local:MyWebView>

web_view.Url = "htmldata";
```

**Output Screenshot**

[image]

The text and video sizes are very small, I don't see any option for increasing the font size of webview, please suggest a solutionn for this issue.

Comment: Can I quickly see what is your parent Layout? Usually, when issues like these happen on iOS it's the constraints my guess is your layout is not letting your WebView match the height of the screen, I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `NavigationDelegate` for **WKWebView** to modify font size of webview .

As follow:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control == null)
    {
        var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
        _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
        _wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new MyNavigationDelegate();
        SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
    }
}

public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        string fontSize = "200%"; // > 100% shows larger than previous
        string stringsss = string.Format("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '{0}'", fontSize);
        WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError err) =>
        {
            if (err != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(err);
            }
            if (result != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        };
        webView.EvaluateJavaScript(stringsss, handler);
        //base.DidFinishNavigation(webView, navigation);
    }

}
```

The default effect :

[image]

The 200% effect:

[image]

=================================Update==================================

If want each element of `Html` to be reszied ,  you can add a header style before the content `Html` .

As follow :

```
string headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'><style>img{max-width:100%}</style></header>";
string finalHtml = headerString + baseHtml ; //baseHtml is current loaded Html
...
```

For example , you can modify the value of `initial-scale` inside the `headerString` .Follow is the sample effect :

```
string headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'><style>img{max-width:100%}</style></header>";
string bodyString = "<html><body><h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1><p>Welcome to WebView.</p><video src='movie.ogg'controls='controls'></video></body></html>";
string finalHtml = headerString + bodyString;
...
```

**initial-scale=1.0** effect :

[image]

**initial-scale=1.5** effect :

[image]

=================================Update==================================

If want the width of Video fit the screen , I suggest that dealing this from `Html` soucre code . Because there are `CSS` styles for `Html` to use .For example , if adding `style='width:100%;'` for **Video** in Html , the Video will fit the width of screen as follow :

[image]

The full code of **Html** :

```
string bodyString = "<html><body><h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1><p>Welcome to WebView.</p><video style='width:100%;' src='movie.ogg'controls='controls'></video></body></html>";
```

==============================Update================================

If unable to modify code of `Html` , also can use `WKNavigationDelegate` to get `video` object from html to modify value for them .

As follow :

```
public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        // 100% width
        string stringHtml =  "var objs = document.getElementsByTagName('video');for(var i=0; i<objs.length; i++) { objs[i].style.width='100%';} ";
        WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError err) =>
        {
            if (err != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(err);
            }
            if (result != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        };
        webView.EvaluateJavaScript(stringHtml, handler);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is working fine for text, the video width not increasing. Any solution to add?

Comment: @SreejithSree There is a solution for reference by adding header for html body . I have updated answer , you can have a look when have time .

Comment: I have tried this, but the problem is video width is exceeding the screen width. Please go through the screenshot attached. How can I set the video width equal to the phone screen width? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YhHveixvXgkY6zL-pyYqH8za2hpqzpXo

Comment: @SreejithSree I have updated answer . I think this better should be dealed with by `Html` . Because there are `CSS` styles for it to use ,and it's easy to implement that from Html .

Comment: Final question: In my case the width value set as 640 like the below screenshot. Can you please have a look? https://drive.google.com/open?id=114cAOqUGLS599jv-glBkbb7PIKgewx7O

Comment: @SreejithSree There is a solution for this , also need to use the first method `WKNavigationDelegate` to get `video` tag and set `100%` value for it . I will update answer , you can have a look at when you have time .

Comment: what i need to give instead of `video`? var objs = document.getElementsByTagName('video')

Comment: @SreejithSree That's not giving instead of `video` . That command is used to find `video` and set width to be `100%`.

Comment: One more question related to this, I have played a video, without passing the video, I click the next button, at that time I need to pause the video automatically. I have used the below codes, but that is not working on the iPad.
string pausefunctionString = @"
                        var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');  
                        [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.pause(); });
                        ";
            web_view.Eval(pausefunctionString);

Comment: @SreejithSree Have a try with this codes : `"var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');for(var i=0; i<videos.length; i++) { videos[i].pause();} "` to replace your `pausefunctionString` . If not works ,you can share the full code of next buton clicked method .