# Execute Javascript in Xamarin.Forms WebView

Tags: javascript, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, wkwebview

im trying to execute Javascript in my Xamarin.Forms WebView by using the tutorial described here:

https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/

Android works really good but I have problems setting this up on iOS. In the iOS custom renderer I basically return the js execute result by

return Task.FromResult(this.EvaluateJavascript(js));

Since last year the iOS api changed and this line throws an error when debugging. It turns out that I should use WkWebViewRenderer instead of WebViewRenderer. I tried to change but EvaluateJavascript() method now wants two arguments... one is the js string and one is a WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler ...

I dont know how to adapt the code in the tutorial... can someone help?

Comment: Try adapting the iOS renderer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63360358/8935380)

Comment: I don't see how i can call this on runtime if I need and get a return value from it. The javascript in your suggested solution looks like a script that runs once when it is added. I need to get javascript results on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed

```
return Task.FromResult(this.EvaluateJavascript(js));
```

to:

```
var x = await webView.EvaluateJavascriptAsync(js);
return x;
```

and now it works

Comment: Ok, you can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
    WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError error) => {
        if (error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
    };
    webView.EvaluateJavaScript(JSCode, handler);
```

Comment: I have a lambda expression where I need to return something. I cannot return the result of webView.EvaluateJavaScript(js, handler); because it is type void

Comment: You can get the result in the handler as I wrote in the answer: `Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());`.

Comment: This is right but how do i get that result into my forms page? Need to fetch it. In my example it was easy though the interface but its not working anymore. I tried to set a variable in the handler: x = result.ToString(); and return x but this somehow only works right if I call the Javascript function twice.

Comment: To your forms page? How about [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)?

Comment: No I mean I call the function with one line over my View Model on my form page by

var result = await EvaluateJavascript("javascriptfunction");

this is giving me back the results from both iOS and Android. Since 

 return Task.FromResult(this.EvaluateJavascript(js));

on iOS side is not working anymore I dont know how to return a value back to my View Model.
I can Console.WriteLine() the handler results but I am not able to return it