# How to fix WebView layout in Xamarin Forms after rotation on iOS (WKWebView)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, layout, webview, wkwebview

I'm encountering problems getting a WebView to take up the whole screen properly in an iOS app using Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1364 & in a ContentPage.  The native control is WkWebView and am testing in an iPhone 12, iOS 14.1 Simulator.

Also, when the device rotates back into portrait orientation, the size of the WebView is wrong, or the content in the WebView is rendered improperly.

The XAML is as follows(note the BackgroundColor relative to the screencaps):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyCompany.MyApp.ViewModels;assembly=MyAssembly"
                x:Class="MyCompany.MyApp.Views.MyWebViewPage"
                BackgroundColor="Green" >
   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
       <viewModel:MyPageViewModel URL="https://login.somepage.com" />
   </ContentPage.BindingContext>
   <ContentPage.Content>
       <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue">
           <WebView x:Name="WebView"
                    BackgroundColor="Black"
                    Source="{Binding URL}"
                    Cookies="{Binding Cookies}">
           </WebView>
       </Grid>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Note: I've tried a lot of things and have removed everything that didn't make a difference.  Have tried FillAndExpand on HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions, as well as Star and Auto sizing on Grid columns/rows.  I removed everything that didn't make a difference from the XAML.
The results are:

Original Portrait(good enough!): [image: WebView in opening in Portrait Mode initially]

After rotating 90 to landscape: [image: WebView after rotating 90 degrees to landscape]

After rotating back to portrait(content issue?): [image: WebView after rotating back to portrait]

What I would like to see is the WebView taking up the whole screen w/ none of the various colors visible(Green, Blue, Black), and after rotation, the content should fit as expected.

I have also tried a Custom Renderer.

```
  public class MyWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
  {
  protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;
            }
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            Bounds = CalculateBounds();
         
            base.LayoutSubviews();
        }

        private CGRect CalculateBounds()
        {
            var screenBounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
            var statusBarHeight = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height;
            nfloat navBarHeight = 0;

            var uiNavController = Window?.RootViewController as UINavigationController;
            if (uiNavController?.TopViewController != null)
            {
                navBarHeight = uiNavController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
            }

            var adjustedHeight = statusBarHeight + navBarHeight;

            var bounds = new CGRect(screenBounds.X, screenBounds.Y + adjustedHeight,
                screenBounds.Width, screenBounds.Height - adjustedHeight);

            return bounds;
        }
      }
```

The results when calculating bounds in MyWebViewRenderer.LayoutSubviews, the results are:

Initial page load in Portrait mode:
(my height calculation is off?)

[image: Initial page load, calculated bounds]

After rotate to landscape(looks ok actually):

[image: After rotate to landscape, calculated bounds]

After rotate back to portrait, the height calc is ok but somehow it's offset:

[image: After rotate back to portrait, calculated bounds]

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You can also add a check to see which page it is, and then keep the orientation fixed for that page

Answer (score 2):

Set the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device and `VerticalOptions` to `FillAndExpand`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336710/webview-text-too-small-cannot-make-bigger-xforms-4-8/63360358#63360358):

```
using Foundation;
using WebKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using MyNamespace.iOS.Renderers;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.iOS.Renderers
{
  public class MyWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            WebView webView = Element as WebView;
            webView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

            //width=device-width sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device
            string jScript = @"" +
                "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); " +
                "meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');" +
                "meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width');" +
                "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

            var userScript = new WKUserScript((NSString)jScript, WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
            
            this.Configuration.UserContentController.AddUserScript(userScript);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I tried it and it didn't make a difference.  The link you gave suggested a few other things to try re: viewport options, which I tried, but no luck so far.

Comment: Add set VerticalOptions to FillAndExpand

Answer (score 1):

Have a try to use `WKUserScript` to ensure the webpag was displayed with the same size as the screen size:

```
public class MyWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            string jScript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

            WKUserScript wkUScript = new WKUserScript(new NSString(jScript),WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd,true);
            WKUserContentController wkUController = new WKUserContentController();
            wkUController.AddUserScript(wkUScript);
            WKWebViewConfiguration webConfig = new WKWebViewConfiguration();

            this.Configuration.UserContentController = wkUController;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I tried it and it did not make a difference.

Comment: Can you have a try with                 `AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;`
?

Comment: I was using that previously, but then I noticed FlexibleDimensions is actually defined like this:  FlexibleDimensions = FlexibleHeight | FlexibleWidth,

So it's basically the same thing...

Comment: I actually opened a bug issue on the xamarin forms project on this.  This all seems like it should work, so am curious if it's a Xamarin.Forms bug.

Comment: Can you please share the issue link here?

Comment: the issue is mostly what I've posted here, link here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12870

Comment: Thanks for your effort, will update you if I find a solution.

Comment: Can you test if it works in a iOS 13 simulator. And try to add width/height there: `<WebView x:Name="WebView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000"...`.